# Making Liquorix default kernel with native NVIDIA drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 for enhanced gaming and realtime functionality

Tags: nvidia, kernel, games, gpu-driver, realtime

I've been interested in running the Liquorix kernel for gaming and realtime performance enhancements. It's a pretty straight foward installation, but I found that it was incompatible with NVIDIA drivers.

Original reference: [here](http://apt-get%20install%20linux-image-liquorix-amd64%20linux-headers-liquorix-amd64) ([archive](https://archive.is/tN4P3))

I was hitting the following errors:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.14.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64 is not supported 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64 (x86_64) 
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.60/build/make.log for more information. 
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.14.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64 is not supported 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64 (x86_64) 
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-384/384.90/build/make.log for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one will note in my thread above, there was a workable suggestion to solve this and so I wanted to share it with the community here since it's a pretty seamless solution and everything is working quite well:

Apparently there's a problem with `nvidia-384` and by going to a PPA with a higher version that is well taken care of, the issue is resolved. These are the steps to install both the `liquorix` kernel and `nvidia-387`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-387
```

This may work with newer versions of Ubuntu, but I've not tested it. Your mileage may vary...